# Bitpay Magento Extension in use anywhere?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

Has anyone in the magento community successfully used the Bitpay extension on a real website accepting bitcoin payments? If so what did you do about the lack of support for magento order status?

https://github.com/bitpay/magento-plugin

We installed this a year ago and quickly discovered a bunch of ToDo's in the code. Seems nothing much has changed and Bitpay doesn't support it.

Wondering if wasting time with Bitpay or if someone got this to work and has positive things to say.

Comment: No one uses Bitpay on Magento? I have yet to find a single live mage site and the github code is still unfinished after all this time

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used CoinGate Magento Bitcoin Extension on one of the client's Magento store to accept Bitcoins. The integration of their Bitcoin checkout is easy, and setup was quick enough using the Magento Connect Manager.

CoinGate is very customer-oriented and reliable. The support is also timely, and payouts are always quick in Dollars, Euros, and Bitcoins. Most importantly, now our clients are happy because their customers are delighted with the fast and intuitive Bitcoin payment process.

I have also shared the installation method of CoinGate on one of my blog posts; I believe you will get benefit by reading it out. Please have a look at it:

[Accept Bitcoins On Magento Stores](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/accept-bitcoin-on-magento/)

Comment: Hey Fayyaz 
Saw that post. Coingate is not available in the US.